# What is the best way to pass data to a Runnable?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable

I generally write most of my code without worrying about threading and such, and get it working and debugged before trying to offload pieces to other threads.  For me, the simplest way to do it is to break the function down into a Runnable or two.  From there I can start a piece via new Thread(runnable).start() and other pieces I start on the main thread via handler.post().

The problem is that I can't pass arguments.  I can sometimes get around this, but too often I end up using non-local variables, which makes things a real mess.  Any ideas on the "correct" way to pass arguments to a runnable?

Comment: Constructor? Setter method? `final`? This is difficult to answer in the abstract.

Comment: http://techtej.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-passing-data-between-main.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually create a new class implementing `Runnable` and pass arguments as constructor parameters and store them in final fields.

If I need a result back from computation I implement `Callable` instead.

I am also using executors rather than threads directly.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without creating a whole new class?

Comment: @EvanLanglois: you may be misunderstanding how Runnables work since you always need to create a concrete class for this, whether it's an anonymous class or a declared class, it is required. Runnable is an interface and cannot be instantiated unless you create a concrete class that implements it. 1+

Comment: @EvanLanglois You could use Java 8 lambda expressions to implement the runnables with minimal overhead while still having access to local variables and method parameters.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - I misunderstood you.  I thought you meant inheriting from Runnable or something.  So you are saying that instead of just supplying a run() method, to also add a constructor and create a specific instance of the runnable local to where it is called to store the variables?

Comment: @isnot2bad: how is the true overhead different with use of Java 8 lambda expressions? Yes the *expression* is more compact, but the compiled code is no different.

Comment: @EvanLanglois: I don't understand your question. "Just adding a run method" does not make a Runnable.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I just had the code in mind. (Although I think the lambda will not be compiled into a separate class too, but just into a synthetic method).

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a public synchronized queue.

Create a global queue of data to process, in order, and then use that queue to access external variables/data. Create a method to add data to the queue, and then one to get the last element and shift it.

This ensures that the data gets across to your thread from an external thread, such as the main program thread, without interrupting the program flow.

The queue can be processed by adding value when data needs to be passed, and the get last element method can be called to get the last date element passed to the thread.

Comment: In this case, this would be a lot of work and debugging.  I generally just need one or two variables to be passed in and the background task will run to completion (such as parsing an input file).  I'm doing anything complex enough (such as socket code) to justify a queue .... it would always be a queue of one!

Comment: True... But it would save you time in the long run, plus the fact that you can potentially reuse, plus the fact that you can just add a variable into the end of the queue. I've done it before, it is glorious ;)